# Remove Youtube Annotation Using iv_load_policy=3

Tags: youtube-api

I am appending `iv_load_policy=3` to the end of my YouTube URL to remove the annotations on the video, but I find it is not working. Looking on Google, it seems like this issue was addressed a year ago. I am wondering if anyone knows if this bug is back or if there is a work around?

I have tested on Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE9 on Win7.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87kezJTpyMI&hd=1&iv_load_policy=3
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#iv_load_policy

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can only use the iv_load_policy when embedding videos using one of the player apis - you can't just change the youtube watch page url.

For example, if you wanted to embed the video you linked above without annotations, you could use this link:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/87kezJTpyMI?hd=1&iv_load_policy=3

Answer (score 1):

Cheers. Wanted to remove the annotations as well from the embedded Youtube video's. Just added &iv_load_policy=3 to the end of the videos URL. Works like a charms :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this in an extension

```
$("div.video-annotations").css("display", "none");
```

Or this in Stylebot extension

```
div.video-annotations {display:none;}
```