# Turn Off Youtube Annotations Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube

There’re currently three ways I know of, to disable annotations in youtube videos:

1. You can use the YouTube settings. This will not work for me, as I do not have (nor want) an account.
2. You can use a specialised extension. That might work, but I’d rather not have a full-fledge extension with a ton of options, just for that.
3. You can use a (ad)blocking extension, and add `||youtube.com/annotations_` to its filters. That suffers from the same issue as the previous point. In addition, it disables them completely, while I simply want them turned off by default (so I have the option to turn them on).

Is it possible to do it using JavaScript? I have a UserScript that already performs some modifications to YouTube’s website, so ideally I’d like to expand it. That’s really the last thing I’m missing.

I ask that answers be constrained to using JS and not browser extensions recommendations. Both because (as mentioned), I already know about those, and because this is as much about the learning process as it is about the result. It’s practice for more UserScripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since youtube sometimes changes the players’s behaviour, I’ll try to keep the code up to date and as robust as possible.

```
var settings_button = document.querySelector(".ytp-settings-button");
settings_button.click(); settings_button.click(); // open and close settings, so annotations label is created

var all_labels = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-menuitem-label");
for (var i = 0; i < all_labels.length; i++) {
  if ((all_labels[i].innerHTML == "Annotations") && (all_labels[i].parentNode.getAttribute("aria-checked") == "true")) { // find the correct label and see if it is active
    all_labels[i].click(); // and in that case, click it
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI - you only need to click the settings button once it appears. And if you want to check if it's already disabled (so you don't re-enable it): `if(document.querySelectorAll("div[role='menuitemcheckbox']")[1].getAttribute("aria-checked") == "true")`

Comment: Can this be modified to also disable Autoplay and work with embedded videos?

Answer (score 0):

User's code is correct, settings need to be click & then:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[role='menuitemcheckbox']")[1].click()
```

I added it to my "turn off autoplay & annotations" script: https://gist.github.com/Sytric/4700ee977f427e22c9b0

---

Previously working JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[aria-labelledby=\"ytp-menu-iv\"]")[0].click()
```

Comment: Does that work for you? Because it does not for me (and neither does the old one, since they added autoplay). Annotations are on by default, so there’s no need to have a check. Autoplay is remembered even if you are not logged in, so I’m not sure why you need a userscript for that.

Comment: This one has been working consistently for me on Firefox - haven't tested on other browsers. I do the check since "sometimes" YT remembers my choice & other times no.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue - I was focused on my own problem of Autoplay, so the document querySelector is just returning the Autoplay button (the first in the array of ytp-segmented-control-other). We can fix this by returning the second element in the array & performing the same function, editing answer now

Answer (score -1):

I know you don't want to use an extension for this but it is the most flexible and easy way to solve your problem.
Extension gives us the power to use a background script through which we can inject css and javascript to opened web page.
I made one extension on this
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-labels-and-end-cards/jinenhpepbpkepablpjjchejlabbpken
This also has a stop-start button for which I just inject the opposite code as before.
If you need any further help on this, i will be happy to do so.

Answer (score -2):

[iv_load_policy (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5)
Values: 1 or 3. Default is 1. Setting to 1 will cause video annotations to be shown by default, whereas setting to 3 will cause video annotations to not be shown by default.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Comment: That only concerns embedded videos, which is not my use-case at all. I specify it’s for a UserScript, and all my solutions concern only the client side. This is to be used with videos I have no control over.

Comment: Uh, you specifically said "Is it possible to do it using JavaScript?".  yes it is possible.  just discover the object containing the video and set the load policy.

you also say"I ask that answers be constrained to using JS and not browser extensions recommendations", yet UserScripts is an extension per se.

if you want a JS solution, find the video object via say jQuery and set the load policy.  there are also RESTful API calls that can do the work for you.

Comment: “Browser extension **recommendations**” means (naturally) something that already exists (hence, “recommending”). You don’t need an extension to run UserScripts (not in Chrome, anyway). While you could argue the UserScript is an extension in itself, it’s one I’m trying to build, not some that is being recommended. Furthermore, your answer (the link) pertains only to embedded videos, which means it won’t work where it matters the mosts — youtube’s website.

Comment: @ZagNut - I too have tried to do this without using embedding - is there a way you've been successful at changing the iv_load_policy directly on a Youtube page (& actually have it take effect)? I've used a few JS techniques to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643785/remove-youtube-annotation-using-iv-load-policy-3

note you only have to append it to url params to grab video with that setting.

this is the solution for doing this with videos FROM youtube.  i can only assume the downvote(s) are because they have a video file they downloaded from youtube and want to enable / disable annotations directly on the video file or something.

through youtube, this is how it's done.

note also the two "div hiding" techniques presented here work as well as page-ready solutions

Answer (score -2):

Here is a nice solution, just hide the div with annotations

`$("div.video-annotations").css("display", "none");`

Comment: Aside from the fact that code doesn’t work (although we can change it to work), it suffers from multiple issues.

1. It only works on annotations present at the time it runs, rendering it essentially useless, since annotations come and go;
2. It hides them, but it doesn’t turn them off, meaning we have to turn them off and on for them to show once more;
3. It doesn’t hide the whole annotation in some cases, as some parts of some annotations don’t have fixed classes we can hook to.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".video-annotations, .ytp-player-content").css("display","none");
});

$("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
 $(".video-annotations, .ytp-player-content").css("display","none");
}); // just listen changes on body content` Hides everything unwanted! And you can unhide them, same way!