# Turning Off Annotations for YouTube Videos by Javascript in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

For my Chrome extension, I want to turn off/on annotations for YouTube videos. Here is an example video containing annotations:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87kezJTpyMI

I searched a lot. There are many API methods provided by YouTube to modify videos but I can not find any JavaScript function to turn off annotations. The most promising solution seemed to be an url parameter (iv_load_policy) hack but it does not work any more.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87kezJTpyMI&hd=1&iv_load_policy=3

How can I turn off annotations by JavaScript for YouTube videos in Chrome extensions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn Off Youtube Annotations Using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687561/turn-off-youtube-annotations-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648179/1661012). It works very well and is kept up-to-date (I’m the author). I’ll paste the current code here as well, but I’ll only try to keep it up-to-date there:

```
var settings_button = document.querySelector(".ytp-settings-button");
settings_button.click(); settings_button.click(); // open and close settings, so annotations label is created

var all_labels = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-menuitem-label");
for (var i = 0; i < all_labels.length; i++) {
  if ((all_labels[i].innerHTML == "Annotations") && (all_labels[i].parentNode.getAttribute("aria-checked") == "true")) { // find the correct label and see if it is active
    all_labels[i].click(); // and in that case, click it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you manually trigger click on annotation off button, with jquery this seems to work:

```
$(".ytp-segmented-control-deselected").click()
```

Comment: Thanks but it only seems to work for HTML5 video player. I also need for Flash Player.

Answer (score -1):

I use this : `$("div.video-annotations").css("display", "none");`

Not sure if it works with flash player!